# View gui after running the program

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote a code to perform training on a dataset. When I click the grade button in the GUI made in tkinter, I want the program to start training. But, when I close the gui window, the program starts the training.

I tried to stop the program execution after the gui window is closed.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import scrolledtext

window = Tk()

window.title("Automated Essay grading System")
window.geometry('500x300')
lbl = Label(window, text="Enter your essay here")
lbl.grid(column=0, row=0)
txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window, width=40, height=10)
txt.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

def main():
    #rest of the code for training 
    btn = Button(window, text="Grade", command=main, padx=10, pady=10, )
    btn.grid(column=1, row=2)
    btn = Button(window, text="Quit",command=window.destroy,padx=10, pady=10)
    btn.grid(column=0, row=3)

    window.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    guiFrame = main()
    guiFrame.mainloop()
```

I want a gui window to be viewed and when the user clicks the grade button, the main function needs to be called and the program must start training. When the window is closed the program execution must terminate.

Comment: if I am not mistaken, your program will work perfectly fine if you remove everything after `window.mainloop()`

Comment: Yes, it worked.

Comment: There shouldn't be two main loops. The main loop blocks and doesnt return until you close the gui window. Since the second main loop depends on the return value of main it will fail as main returns None. Also the grade button just calls main (i.e. itself), so all it will be doing is adding more widgets to the window on top of the existing ones each time you press it.